# Estimating cointegrating equations in VEC models

Tags: maximum-likelihood, cointegration, vector-error-correction-model

When using the Johansen MLE procedure to estimate a VEC model, is it true to say that the cointegrating equations are estimated **simultaneously** with the other parameters of the VEC model? Meaning estimating the cointegrating equations on their own would give different estimates?

Comment: Thanks you for this !